# Get wordpress posts by time and date

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm trying to get wordpress post by date and time, 
for example from 02/01/2014 to 02/05/2014 and time 17:10, somebody knows?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [WP_Query class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) can fulfill this. Just set up a new query, passing in the appropriate arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
         // limit to between these dates
        array(
            'after'     => '2014-02-01',
            'before'    => '2014-02-05', //remove this line if no upper limit
            'inclusive' => true,
            ),
         // limit to posts before 17:10 (not tested)
        array(
            'hour'      => 17,
            'minute'    => 10,
            'compare'   => '<=',
            ),
         // limit to posts after 08:30
        array(
            'hour'      => 08,
            'minute'    => 30,
            'compare'   => '>=',
            ),
        ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
$my_date_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then run your loop using the query object you just instatiated:

```
<?php if ( $my_date_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <!-- the loop -->
  <?php while ( $my_date_query->have_posts() ) : $my_date_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <!-- end of the loop -->

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else:  ?>
  <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The date parameters section gives a good overview of the types of post queries you can create: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

**N.B** Don't use `query_posts`. From [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts):

> query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main
>   query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is
>   inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some
>   circumstances

Comment: looks good, and you know how i can put a filter like time, 
from this time until now, for example?

Comment: time argument added, modify and add another to get a time range

Comment: show the post but the time i think doesnt work, and why don't show me the post from today for example, 2014-02-07, i have post of today

Comment: Do you know i can put end time,for example from this date and this time until this date and this time?

Comment: Yes, the first array in the `date_query` are the start and end dates. The second array currently specifies that the post must be before 17:10. You can add another in there to say the post must be after a time by using the `>=` comparison operator.

Comment: I have added a 3rd array as example. So the current example will only return posts for between 2014-02-01 to 2014-02-05 that were posted between 08:30 and 17:10

Comment: I Don't know why don't show the actual post when you put in the date, "before" => '2014-02-07', i have a lot of new post today, but doenst show, show only from yesterday. and if i put 2014-02-06, show from  2014-02-05, what is wrong?

Comment: If you want to include posts up to today then just omit that line altogether. The query will just get all posts after the `after` date.

Comment: now i think is working, thanks so much for you help, i will check and i'll told, i have here i think 20.000 pages hahahaa, so much